# Remove Bootstrap Carousel slide delay

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

As the question states i need my carousel to set its active right away. I do not want to give up the animation but have the indicators activate instantly. This is what i tried, to no avail
I have also modified my carousel to used a fade animation instead of the default sliding it does

script code:

```
$('.full.portfolio .carousel-indicators li').click(function (){
    $('.full.portfolio .carousel-indicators li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

as you may have guessed , .full.portfolio is my carousel

Answer (score 1):

```
$('you carousel id or class').carousel({
  interval: 2000 // set your desired interval
})
```

reference http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

Comment: that doesn't solve my problem. what i am trying to do is have the controls (indicators) become active when when the transition to the next slide starts, not when it ends

Answer (score 0):

If your using bootstrap 2.3.2 you can modify the javascript carousel class definition as follows;

The existing code waits for the 'slid' event before updating the indicators, so
the first thing to do is disable this code, which is found in the slide function on
the carousel prototype.
Comment it out like so...

```
// disabled original code that waits for the slider transition to complete before
// setting the active indicator
//this.$element.one('slid', function () {
  //var $nextIndicator = $(that.$indicators.children()[that.getActiveIndex()])
  //$nextIndicator && $nextIndicator.addClass('active')
//})
```

Now you need a new function similar to getActiveIndex, but it also needs to check if there is
a next/prev index pending.
Add this function to the carousel prototype...

```
// get the index of the carousel item about the be shown
// or the current item, if not transitioning
, getNextActiveIndex: function () {
    var nextActive = this.$element.find('.item.next')
      , prevActive = this.$element.find('.item.prev')
    this.$active = this.$element.find('.item.active')

    if (!nextActive.length) {
      nextActive = prevActive 
    }
    if (!nextActive.length) {
      nextActive = this.$active
    }

    this.$items = this.$active.parent().children()
    return this.$items.index(nextActive)
  }
```

Now to set the active/next indicator. This needs to be done after the 'prev' or 'next' css class
has been added to the carousel item.
So put this code at the end of the slide function just before the return...

```
  // by now the 'next' or 'prev' css class has been added to the carousel item
  // so we can call getNextActiveIndex 
  var $nextIndicator = $(this.$indicators.children()[this.getNextActiveIndex()])
  $nextIndicator && $nextIndicator.addClass('active')
```